# What is shortcut to this contest algebra problem about polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

The polynomial $P(x)=x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 +cx + d$ has the property that $p(k)=11k$ for $k=1,2,3,4$. Compute $c$.

The answer is $-39$.

Comment: A little rude to be dictating how people should help you with their time by giving you answers to your questions.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - i think a short solution would help any math-blind person like me.

Comment: I'm sure you do. But it's still rude to try to dictate to people when you are asking for their help. [Limosneros con garrote](http://translate.google.com/?hl=en&tab=wT#es|en|Limosneros%20con%20garrote) often find themselves with no help.

Comment: @Arturo: There is apparently a movie with the [same](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0277097/) title!

Comment: @Victor:Really, an interrogative sentence (title) without a question mark ?!

Comment: @MaX: It's a common phrase, at least in Mexico.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin:Aw, I didn't knew that before. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $Q(x)=P(x)-11x$.  Then the roots of $Q(x)$ are $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$.

But if the roots of a monic quartic are $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$, then the sum of the products of the $r_i$, taken $3$ at a time, is the negative of the coefficient of $x$.  For $1,2,3,4$ this sum of products is $50$. A simple way to calculate is to divide $24$ by $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$ and add up the results.

We conclude that the coefficient of $x$ in $Q(x)$ is $-50$. This is $c-11$, so $c=-39$.

There may be a simpler approach, but probably this essentially automatic use of one of the Viète relations is the intended argument.