# Polynomial Function that contains a property

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is shortcut to this contest algebra problem about polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89476/what-is-shortcut-to-this-contest-algebra-problem-about-polynomial)

The polynomial $P(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ has the property that $P(k)=11k$ for $k=1,2,3,4$. Compute $c$.

Comment: Hint: What can you say about root of the polynomial $P(x)-11x$? How are the roots related to coefficients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(x)-11x=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$ since it is monic, has degree four, and is zero at $1,2,3,4$.  the coefficient of $x$ is $-(1\cdot2\cdot3+1\cdot2\cdot4+1\cdot3\cdot4+2\cdot3\cdot4)=-(6+8+12+24)=-50$.  hence the coefficient of $x$ in $P(x)$ is $c=-39$.  likewise, $a=-(4+3+2+1)=-10$, $b=1\cdot2+1\cdot3+1\cdot4+2\cdot3+2\cdot4+3\cdot4=2+3+4+6+8+12=35$ and  $d=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4=24$ so that $P(x)=x^4-10x^3+35x^2-39x+24$

Comment: "since it has degree four and is zero at 1,2,3,4" *and is monic*.